# HttpException: -404 Failed to connect to remote server on mac while running Docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, sparql, docker-machine, virtuoso

I am getting `Error HttpException: -404 Failed to connect to remote server` while running jar file from docker execute a command `docker exec -it Test_docker java -jar TestDocker.jar`.

> Note: I have created docker on windows, Where my docker machine IP is 192.168.99.100 and my docker exec command running successfully.I am accessing SPARQL endpoint on windows using URL: http://192.168.99.100:8890/sparql this will work perfectly. But when I am using same on mac it will give me an error which I mention above. I have also try to change SPARQL endpoint on my code as http://localhost:8890/sparql but not work well though it will work fine on chrome browser on mac while executing through command it will giving me an error.

Here my docker-compose file,

```
version: "3"
services:
  jardemo_test:
    container_name: Test_docker
    image: "java:latest"
    working_dir: /usr/src/myapp
    volumes:
      - /docker/test:/usr/src/myapp    
    tty: true
    depends_on:
      - virtuoso

  virtuoso:
    container_name: virtuoso_docker
    image: openlink/virtuoso_opensource
    ports:
      - "8890:8890"
      - "1111:1111"
    environment:      
      DB_USER_NAME: dba
      DBA_PASSWORD: dba
      DEFAULT_GRAPH: http://localhost:8890/test
    volumes:
      - /docker/virtuoso-test/:/data
```

> Note: I have tried all the way to set the environment variable on docker-compose file default graph URL with all the IP address but it won't allow.Which IP I have tried all combination listed below.
>   Though I am getting the same error.

- DEFAULT_GRAPH: http://localhost:8890/test
- DEFAULT_GRAPH: http://127.0.0.1:8890/test
- DEFAULT_GRAPH: http://0.0.0.0:8890/test

below is my `docker-compose ps` result,

```
 $ docker-compose ps
 Name                    Command               State                       Ports
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Test_docker      /bin/bash                        Up
virtuoso_docker   /opt/virtuoso-opensource/b ...   Up      0.0.0.0:1111->1111/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8890->8890/tcp
```

Below is my code which I am using,

```
QueryExecution qexec = QueryExecutionFactory.sparqlService("http://localhost:8890/sparql", queryString);
ResultSet results1 = qexec.execSelect();
```

> Info: After running successful docker I have accessed the http://localhost:8890/sparql. it will successfully run on the mac.

Can anybody please help me to solve this issue?Also, welcome your suggestions and thought.Thanks for the help and your time in advance.

Comment: There are so many possibilities here... Can your Mac connect to your Windows? What IP address does Windows have? (Note that the docker environment typically must have its own.) Have you adjusted firewalls on Mac and Windows to permit the desired communications? Note that `localhost` and `127.0.0.1` both refer to "this machine I'm on"; these addresses will never reach another machine/environment. `0.0.0.0` only has meaning as a listener; you cannot contact another machine running with that IP address.

Comment: One definite thing -- `DEFAULT_GRAPH` should be set using the FQDN and HTTP Port of your Virtuoso instance, such that it's dereferenceable and consistent from remote hosts. Similarly, you should adjust the `DefaultHost` in the `[URIQA]` stanza of `virtuoso.ini` to use that FQDN and port.

Comment: Also your question tags -- I don't think this is really about `docker-compose`, `docker-machine`, nor `sparql`. Inappropriate tags will not get you faster or better answers.

Comment: On re-re-re-reading this question, I wonder whether the mention of Windows is a distraction. Are the current issues happening when running your docker container on your Mac? I suggest rearranging your question, so it's clear (1) what the current problem is, (2) what you've tried, and (3) what other information is tangential.

Comment: Hi,@TallTed I appreciate as you always ready to help.I have solved my problem please check below for the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my colleague suggested, The problem is that the code in de docker file sees the docker as the local host. The IP-address 192.168.99.100 is also not known because mac doesn't have it. To solve the problem of connections, docker uses its own network.The docker-compose service names are used as the reference. So instead of using http://localhost:8890/sparql, you should use http://virtuoso:8890/sparql as virtuoso is the service name.

I tried this and it will solve my problem.